# Auto Import Blender Textures into Unity Blend File

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I am using a .blend file that I import in Unity, which contains a few animations. Unity does not seem to be able to import the textures of the model though. I have noticed that if i import an fbx for a single animation along with an fbm folder containing the textures(same name as the fbx), it does actually locate the textures, but that doesn't work with the .blend file.

I have used Blender's File->External Data->Pack All Into Files, to extract the textures folder, which I then import into Unity. And as I said, Unity does not recognize the folder if I drag/drop the whole blend file.

Is there a way to have Unity auto load the textures of the blend file, the same way it does for an fbx ? Am i maybe doing something wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using?